# Google charts X-axis don't look so good

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I draw a chart using google charts API. and i get this chart:
[image]

My problem in this chart is the X-axis. The labels are not in look so good.
if I have more Strings in X-axis it's look like this:
[image]

I think the problem is because the X column type is string and not DATETIME.
How i change the column type in google charts?
Or How i change the X-axis without changin the column type?
I add the script here below...

**PHP code**:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','123456');
mysql_select_db('db_statmarket',$connection);

$result2 = mysql_query('select sum(`How much read from customer`) as Leads, Date from monitor group by Date;',$connection) or die('cannot show tables');

$json = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $json[] = $row;
}

$str='[\'Date\', \'Leads\'],';
foreach($json as $key=>$value){

$str = $str.'['.'\''.$value["Date"].'\''.', '.$value["Leads"].'],'; 

}
$str = substr($str, 0, -1);
$str = '['.$str.']';
    $result1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM monitor ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1;',$connection) or die('cannot show tables');
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
```

**JS code**:

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $str?>);

    var options = {
        title: '',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        width: 1000,
        backgroundColor: '#efeff0',
        is3D: true,
        chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: {
                       stroke: '#efeff1',
                       strokeWidth: 1}},
        height: 300

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
```

**HTML code**:

```
<div id="curve_chart" class="plot" style="width: 50% ; height: 400px ; float:left; margin-left:9%;"></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found The answer.

I share It for all. so if somebody stuck, like me. will continue with this help quickly.

I create new variable: `var showEvery = parseInt(data.getNumberOfRows() / 4);`

And in the option attribute i add: `hAxis: {showTextEvery: showEvery}`

so the JS code seems like this:

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo $str?>);

    var showEvery = parseInt(data.getNumberOfRows() / 4);
    
    var options = {
        title: 'Title',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        width: 1000,
        backgroundColor: '#efeff0',
        is3D: true,
        chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: {
                       stroke: '#efeff1',
                       strokeWidth: 1}},
        hAxis: {showTextEvery: showEvery},
        height: 300
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can force the x-axis of a BarChart setting the `hAxis.viewWindow.min` and `hAxis.viewWindow.max`:

```
hAxis: {
    viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    },
    ticks: [0, 50, 100] // display labels every 50
}
```

This will work for numbers or percentages, to use with dates is a bit more complex: checking [Customizing Axes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes) in Google API, there are two solutions:

- You can change your **major X axis** to **discrete** and date type

> The major axis of a chart can be either discrete or continuous. When using a discrete axis, the data points of each series are evenly spaced across the axis, according to their row index. When using a continuous axis, the data points are positioned according to their domain value.

- Read, in the [Customizing Axes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes) link part which starts with `Help! My chart has gone wonky!` where explains the steps how to change from `date` to `string` and then customize it...

Comment: It just get it worst. and i cants use some of the functions in the API like:      dataView.setColumns([{calc: function(data, row) { return ''; }, type:'string'}, 0, 1]);

Comment: play a bit around with it, you will find your needs, this works with percentages, you need dates...

Comment: How i change it to Dates?